# ¿Como capturar el dato de un select para actualizarlo?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

El inconveniente que tengo es cuando quiero actualizar un select de un id especifico pero cuando le doy editar siempre me muestra es el dato del select del primer id insertado pero los demas campos si los muestras correctamente menos el del select.

Este es el archivo **prestamos.php** donde me lista los prestamos

```
<?php
require('../conexion.php');
$con=Conectar();

$sql="SELECT id_prestamo, pre_cliente, fecha, monto, forma_de_pago, fiador, 
cliente.cedula,cliente.nombre, cliente.apellido from prestamo
inner join cliente
on prestamo.pre_cliente=cliente.id_cliente
ORDER BY id_prestamo ASC";

?>

<table id="grid" class="table table-hover table-condensed table-bordered 
nowrap dt-responsive" cellpadding="0">
<thead>
<tr class="active">

<th>Cedula</th>
<th>Cliente</th>
<th>Monto $ </th>
<th>No Cuotas</th>
<th>Interes %</th>
<th>Fecha Prestamo</th>
<th>Fiador</th>
<th>Forma de pago</th>
<th>Saldo actual</th>
<th>Abonos</th>
<th>Opciones</th>

</tr>
</thead>
<?php

$stmt=$con->prepare($sql);
$resultado=$stmt->execute();
$rows=$stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

foreach ($rows as $prestamo) {

?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $prestamo->cedula?></td>
<td><?php echo $prestamo->nombre." ".$prestamo->apellido?></td>
<td><?php echo $prestamo->monto?></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td><?php echo $prestamo->fecha?></td>
<td><?php echo $prestamo->fiador?></td>
<td><?php echo $prestamo->forma_de_pago?></td>
<td></td>

// aqui es dode paaso el id_prestamo al formulario de actualizar
<td align="center"><a href="frm_editar.php?id_prestamo=<?php echo $prestamo-
>id_prestamo?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check" title="Editar">
</span></a>

<?php
}
?>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<div align="center">
<br /><br />

<?php
if ($x==1) {
echo '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable" data-
dismiss="alert" style="width:300px">Se actualizado el prestamo 
correctamente</div>';
}
if ($x==2) {
echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable" data-dismiss="alert" 
style="width:300px">Problemas al actualizar el prestamo</div>';
}
if ($x==3) {
echo '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable" data-
dismiss="alert" style="width:300px">Se ha eliminado el prestamo 
correctamente</span>';
}
if ($x==4) {
echo '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable" data-
dismiss="alert" style="width:300px">Problemas al eliminar el prestamo,  
Primero elimina el prestamo</div>';
}
if ($x==5){
echo '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable" data-
dismiss="alert" style="width:300px">Se ha agregado el prestamo correctamente 
</div>';
}
if ($x==6){
echo '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable" data-
dismiss="alert" style="width:300px">Problemas al agregar el prestamo</div>';
}
?>
</div>       
</div>
```

Este es el archivo **frm_editar.php**

```
<?php
require('../conexion.php');
$con=Conectar();


$prestamos=$con->query("SELECT p.id_prestamo, p.fecha, p.monto, 
p.forma_de_pago, p.fiador, c.cedula, c.nombre, c.apellido from prestamo p, 
cliente c
where (c.id_cliente=p.pre_cliente)
and (p.id_prestamo='".$_GET['id_prestamo']."')")->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$cliente=$con->query("SELECT * FROM cliente")->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Actualizar Prestamo</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="wid=device-wid, user-scalable=no, initial-
scale=1.0, minium-scale=1.0">

<script>
  function numeros(e){
    tecla = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;

//Tecla de retroceso para borrar, siempre la permite
if (tecla==8){
  return true;
}

// Patron de entrada, en este caso solo acepta numeros
patron =/[0-9]/;
tecla_final = String.fromCharCode(tecla);
return patron.test(tecla_final);
}
</script>
<script>
function letras(e) {
tecla = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;
if (tecla==8) return true;
patron =/[A-Za-z\s]/;
te = String.fromCharCode(tecla);
return patron.test(te);
}
</script>
</head>
<body >
<div class="container">
<br>
<div class="panel panel-success" align="center">
<div class="panel-heading"><h3>Actualizar Prestamo</h3>
</div>


<div class="panel-body">
<form class="form-horizontal" action="actualizar.php" style="margin:0 auto" 
method="POST">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Cliente</label>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
       <select name="cliente" class="form-control">
        <?php
        foreach ($cliente as $clientes) {

          if($clientes->id_cliente == $prestamos->pre_cliente){
            $s = "selected";
          }
          else{
            $s = "";
          }
          ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $clientes->id_cliente ?>" <?php echo $s; 
 ?>>
            <?php echo $clientes->nombre. "-" .$clientes->apellido." ". 
 $clientes->cedula; ?>
          </option>
          <?php
  }//cerramo el ciclo mientras
  ?>
 </select>
</div>
</div>

<?php

foreach ($prestamos as $prestamo) {

?>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Monto</label>
<div class="col-lg-4">

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="monto" placeholder="Monto" 
onkeypress="return numeros(event)" required name="monto" value="<?php echo 
$prestamo->monto?>" />
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Fecha</label>
<div class="col-lg-4">
<input type="date"  name="fecha" id="fecha" value="<?php echo $prestamo-
>fecha?>" required/>
</input>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Modo de pago</label>
<div class="col-lg-4">
<select name="formapago" id="formapago">
  <option value="0">Seleccione</option>
  <?php
/*   while ($pagos=$formapago->fetch_object())
{*/
if ($prestamo->forma_de_pago=="Semanal")
{
  ?>

  <option value="Semanal" selected="selected">Semanal</option>
  <option value="Quincenal">Quincenal</option>
  <option value="Mensual">Mensual</option>
  <?php
}
if ($prestamo->forma_de_pago=="Quincenal")
{
  ?>

  <option value="Quincenal" selected="selected">Quincenal</option>
  <option value="Semanal">Semanal</option>
  <option value="Mensual">Mensual</option>
  <?php
}
if ($prestamo->forma_de_pago=="mensual"){
  ?>
  <option value="Semanal" >Semanal</option>
  <option value="Quincenal" >Quincenal</option>
  <option value="Mensual" selected="selected">Seleccione</option>
  <?php
}
?>
</select>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-lg-4 control-label">fiador</label>
<div class="col-lg-4">

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="fiador" placeholder="fiador"  
required name="fiador" value="<?php echo $prestamo->fiador?>" />
</div>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
<br>
<div class="row col-md-offset-1">
<button type="submit" name="actualizar" class="btn btn-success col-xs-12 
col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">Actualizar</button>

<button type="reset" name="limpiar" class="btn btn-primary col-xs-12 col-md-
2 col-md-offset-1 ">Limpiar</button>

<button type="button" onclick="location='prestamos.php'" class="btn btn-
danger col-xs-12 col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">Cancelar</button>
</div>

<input name="id_prestamo" type="hidden" value="<?php echo 
$_GET['id_prestamo']?>"/>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../paginacion/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../paginacion/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No entiendo lo que planteas. ¿Te falla un dato en un select?
Yo probaría varias cosas para ir aislando el problema: debuguear el $_POST que recibes cuando envías el formulario, si esta bien que se guarda en la base de datos, si estas enviando datos de esta al formulario cuales son esos datos, etc.

Comment: @Orici Lo que planteo es que en el formulario editar no me trae el dato correcto del select, pero en los demas campos si. ya hice el debuger y me trae correcto el id_prestamo pero del cliente no! que es el del select